# My website keywords are not indexing. What should i do?

Tags: web-development, website-design

My website keywords are not indexing. I have changed all pages meta and updated new content but still my keywords are not showing in Google serp. What should i do please tell me some suggestion. I am doing all the off page activities of the website last 2 months.

Answer (score 2):

Don't just depend on specifying keywords to make it work. Google indexing is much more intelligent than it was years ago when simply specifying the keywords was enough. Google will now detect and choose its own keywords out of the content of your page and decide if the keywords you specify are appropriate for the page in question. Additionally your keywords should be page rather than site specific, so do choose a few keywords to reflect your entire site but then specify additional keywords for the individual pages.

A good source of inspiration is to take a look at https://blog.kissmetrics.com/simple-guide-to-seo/ by kissmetrics which provides a blog article on a simple guide to search engine optimization which is what you are after.

Comment: One up-vote for not pointing them to MOZ but KissMetrics! MOZ is not on my list of favorites, but KissMetrics is. Most all of these miss the mark. Both MOZ and KissMetrics do have some good stuff. It is just that MOZ brings a lot of confused people here. ;-) Also, using the term keywords just clouds the SEO B.S. that you allude to. You are right, Google is far smarter than this! Google never actually made keyword matches even though it looked like they did. It is far more semantic based. It pays to know semantics as in linguistics and not semantic web if you want to get an idea. Cheers!!